# split a file based upon line number

Tags: bash, file, split

I have a large file that needs to be slitted based on line numbers.
For instance , my file is like that:

```
aaaaaa 
bbbbbb  
cccccc
dddddd
****** //here blank line//
eeeeee
ffffff
gggggg
hhhhhh
*******//here blank line//
ıııııı
jjjjjj
kkkkkk
llllll
******
//And so on...
```

I need two separate files as such that one file should have first 4 lines, third 4 lines, fifth 4 lines in it and the other file should have second 4 lines, fourth 4 lines, sixth 4 lines in it and so on. how can I do that in bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

EVEN="even.log"
ODD="odd.log"

line_count=0
block_count=0
while read line
do
    # ignore blank lines
    if [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
      if [ $(( $block_count % 2 )) -eq 0 ]; then
        # even
        echo "$line" >> "$EVEN"
      else
        # odd
        echo "$line" >> "$ODD"
      fi
      line_count=$[$line_count +1]
      if [ "$line_count" -eq "4" ]; then
        block_count=$[$block_count +1]
        line_count=0
      fi
    fi
done < "$1"
```

The first argument is the source file: `./split.sh split_input`

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the number of the line, `NR`:

```
$ awk 'NR%10>0 && NR%10<5' your_file > file1
$ awk 'NR%10>5' your_file > file2
```

- If it is `10K + n, 0 < n < 5`, then goes to the first file.
- If it is `10K + n, n > 5`, then goes to the second file.

In one line:

```
$ awk 'NR%10>0 && NR%10<5 {print > "file1"} NR%10>5 {print > "file2"}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
4

6
7
8
9

11
12
13
14

16
17
18
19

21
22
23
24

26
27
28
29

31
32
33
34

36
37
38
39

41
42
43
44

46
47
48
49

51
$ awk 'NR%10>0 && NR%10<5 {print > "file1"} NR%10>5 {print > "file2"}' a
$ cat file1
1
2
3
4
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
31
32
33
34
41
42
43
44
51
$ cat file2
6
7
8
9
16
17
18
19
26
27
28
29
36
37
38
39
46
47
48
49
```

Comment: As my own solution the tool you use (`awk`) is not part of the `bash`. Just to notice that.

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks @urzeit . Using `head` and `tail` is not enough for this case, unless you want to do very tricky things. `awk` is installed in almost all servers, so just see if it works to the OP.

Comment: @Kent yes, just updated accordingly and added a test.

Comment: I have actually 201 lines in each block of data. Could we split every first 201 lines to file 1 and second 201 lines to file2 by using above script?

Comment: Yes, sure @user2100161, just replace alls `10`s with `201` and it will do the trick.

Comment: That is what I m looking for. that is great job fedorqui. really appreciate for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `head` and `tail` (which are not be part of the bash itself):

```
head -n 20 <file> | tail -n 5
```

gives you the lines 15 to 20.

This is however inefficient, if you want to get multiple sections of your file, since it has to be parsed again and again. In this case I'd prefer some *real* scripting.

Comment: Thanks urzeit; I am looking for a script as you said.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your fat reply and help.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to treat blank-line-separated paragraphs as the records, and print odd-numbered and even-numbered records to different files:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{
    outfile = (NR % 2 == 1) ? "file1" : "file2"
    print > outfile
}' file
```

Comment: Dear glenn; it does not give file 2 as I expect. ıt gives only file1. but file 1 is the same as the file (original file). script just gives the original file with a new name of file1. but approach is nice. how can we improve it?

Comment: Hmm, works for me. What is your OS? What version of awk are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This script prints lines from file 1.txt with indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, ...

```
i=0
while read p; do
  if [ $i%8 -lt 4 ]
  then
    echo $p
  fi
  let i=$i+1
done < 1.txt
```

This script prints lines with indexes 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, ...

```
i=0
while read p; do
  if [ $i%8 -gt 3 ]
  then
    echo $p
  fi
  let i=$i+1
done < 1.txt
```